# variables AND form request - WebMatrix

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

i'm trying to add information from a form to a row in a database that corresponds with the logged on user:

UPDATED: This is the working code

```
@{
Layout = "~/_template1.cshtml";

var db = Database.Open("stayinflorida");
var CurrentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var userdetails = ("SELECT * from UserProfile WHERE UserId=@0");
var quserdetails = db.QuerySingle(userdetails, CurrentUser);

if (IsPost){
var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1 WHERE UserID=@2";
db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"]);
Response.Redirect("~/Account/MyDetails1.cshtml");
}
}
```

How do i change it so that instead of users the userId='8', i actually use the user ID of the logged in user? I would normally do this using @0. but that's already been used to request data from the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine but you missed one entry userid = @2

```
var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1 WHERE UserID=@2";
db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"], WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

or

```
var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1 WHERE UserID=@2";
db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"], CurrentUser );
```

Every parameter must be entered. @0, @1,@2 stands for Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"], CurrentUser

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var db = Database.Open("stayinflorida");
var TheUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var userdetails = ("SELECT * from UserProfile WHERE UserId=@0");
var data = db.Query(sqlQ, TheUser);
```

Edit:

> Each SQL statement gets its own set of 'variables called @0, @1, @2 and so forth. They only exist for that one line so you can use that concept over and over.

Comment: Each SQL statement gets its own set of 'variables called @0, @1, @2 and so forth.  They only exist for that one line so you can use that concept over and over.

Comment: Thanks Knox. So i was to change the code to this... var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1 WHERE UserID=@2"; how would i populate the user ID from the variable?

Comment: Ah man, i've sorted it, thanks so much! it makes much more sense that each @ variable only exists for one line.! Do you want to put it down as an answer, and i'll accept. Thanks again buddy!